# How to manage a question which answer might change at some point?

Tags: discussion, closing, editing

I just answered to this question : [How to enable Survival Mode in Fallout 1.4 Patch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258573/how-to-enable-survival-mode-in-fallout-1-4-patch). The problem was that the mode that the user was looking for was not implemented yet. The answer is good at the moment, but when the patch in question will be released, it won't be anymore.

What is the good thing to do in such a case ? Should the question be closed or deleted, or should I edit my answer when the patch will be released, so that it explains how to activate the corresponding mode ?

Answer (score 1):

If what is being asked about can't be played yet, and hasn't been available for play ever, flag to close it.  We don't deal with unknown mechanics that don't yet exist.

That said, it looks like the data is somewhat there.  If they're asking about something that currently exists in some form or fashion, it's fine.  If it can be played, it's on-topic.

For this question, the asker is asking about a mode that's only been half implemented, it seems.  They're asking why it doesn't work, which is a valid question; he pushed the button, but it's not doing anything.  Why?  Now, if they were asking about how the mechanics of this mode worked, and nobody can play it yet, that's where it becomes off-topic.

Easy rule of thumb: Is it in-game and can it be played?  Then it's fine.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, however I am not sure it is answering what I am asking there. At the moment, the mode is partially integrated in the game, but is not working yet. So right now, my answer explaining that the patch is not fully released yet is good. However, when the patch will be released, the mode will be fully working, and so my answer won't be good anymore at this point in time. What I am asking is if, at the moment when the patch will be released, I should edit my answer so that it will explain how to use the game mode, or if the post should be deleted, closed...

Comment: We're generally not in the habit of deleting outdated questions.  If you want to, you can update it once the mode becomes fully playable, or not.  Someone else can answer to fill in that gap if you don't.